# What is the Jersey 2 replacement for HttpRequestContext.getEntity(Class)?

Tags: jersey, jersey-2.0

When a resource attempts to parse the request entity, I'd like to log the entity's String representation so I can reproduce the problem at a later time. In the past I used to:

1. Cache the entity before it was read by the resource.
2. Invoke HttpRequestContext.getEntity(String.class).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been replaced by [ContainerRequest.readEntity(Class)](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/latest/jersey/org/glassfish/jersey/server/ContainerRequest.html#readEntity%28java.lang.Class%29) in Jersey 2.0